Smooth circle bundles over blowup of weighted proective space
Consider the toric variety $X$ given by the (possibly weighted) blowup of the weighted $\mathbb{CP}_{[a_0, a_1, a_2]}$ in two of the three fixed points. If I am not mistaken, the second cohomology of $X$ should be generated by the canonical divisor $K$ of $\mathbb{CP}_{[a_0, a_1, a_2]}$ and by the two exceptional divisors of the blow-ups $E_1$ and $E_2$. I have two questions:

What is the canonical divisor of $X$ in terms of $K, E_1$ and $E_2$?
Most importantly, what are the constraints on $k, e_1, e_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that the circle bundle with Chern class $kK + e_1E_1 + e_2E_2$ is smooth?

By weighted blowup I actually mean the orbifold correspoding to the labeled Delzant polytope with labels on the blowed-up edges greater than 1, which is a thing in symplectic geometry but I am not sure about what it corresponds to in algebraic geometry. Feel free to forget such condition and only take the standard blowup if it makes things easier.
Given that the blowup differentially is implemented with connected sums, I suspect this question boils down to some differential topology argument about gluing things in an equivariant way.
